# retrieve data from db using function pdo

Tags: php, function, pdo

here is the code before implementing the function,

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status= :published ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5');
    $stmt->execute(array(':published' => 'published'));
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $contents = $result['content'];
    $title = $result['title']; 
....
```

this works fine. Then i moved db connecting commands to separate php file(functions.php). and created this function,

```
function run_db($sqlcom,$exe){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);
    $stmt->execute($exe);
    $data_db = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
    return $data_db;
}
```

Then i changed first mentioned code like this,

```
try {
    $data_db=run_db('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status= :published ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5',array(':published' => 'published'));   
    while ($result = $data_db) {
    $contents = $result['content'];
    $title = $result['title'];
```

Then all i got was one post repeating infinitely. Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Comment: You shouldn't connect every time you call a function. You'd kill your database server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to this:

```
function run_db($sqlcom,$exe){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);
    $stmt->execute($exe);
    return $stmt;
}
```

and the call to that function to:

```
try {
    $stmt = run_db('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status= :published ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5',array(':published' => 'published'));   
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $contents = $result['content'];
        $title = $result['title'];
```

---

**EDIT:** Better solution is the one that **jeroen** advices - to **return all the fetched objects at once**:

```
function run_db($sqlcom,$exe){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);
    $stmt->execute($exe);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Then calling this way:

```
try {
    $data = run_db('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status= :published ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5',array(':published' => 'published'));   
    foreach($data as $result) {
        $contents = $result['content'];
        $title = $result['title'];
```

---

**EDIT 2:** Anyway - wrapping such a logic into one function is not very good idea. now You are limited with executing of only `SELECT` queries and the resulting array containing always only record's associative array. What if You would like to (for any reason) retrieve the array of **objects**, or even **only one single value**? What if You would like to execute `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` queries???

If You for sure want to go this way, then I'd suppose creating a class with functions like this:

```
class MyPDO {
    private $connection;

    static $instance;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    static function getInstance() {
        return self::$instance ?  : self::$instance = new MyPDO;
    }

    // retrieves array of associative arrays
    function getAssoc($sqlcom, $exe) {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sqlcom);
        $stmt->execute($exe);

        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    // retrieves array of objects
    function getObj($sqlcom, $exe) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);
        $stmt->execute($exe);

        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    // retireves one single value, like for SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE column = true
    function getOne($sqlcom, $exe) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);
        $stmt->execute($exe);

        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

    // just executes the query, for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE ...
    function exec($sqlcom, $exe){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);

        return $stmt->execute($exe);
    }
}
```

Then You can call it this way:

```
try {
    $pdo = MyPDO::getInstance();
    foreach($pdo->getAssoc('MySQL QUERY'), array($param, $param)) as $result) {
        print_r($result);
    }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yes i implement your advice to use class. thx for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Just return the statement:

```
function run_db($sqlcom,$exe){
    static $conn;
    if ($conn == NULL)
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlcom);
    $stmt->execute($exe);
    return $stmt;
}


try {
    $stmt=run_db('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status= :published ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5',array(':published' => 'published'));   
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $contents = $result['content'];
    $title = $result['title'];
```

And you could also set the default fecth mode on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the correct answers that return `$stmt` from the function, would be to [fetch all rows](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) in the function and use a `foreach` in your main code:

In function:

```
...
$data_db = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
return $data_db;
```

Outside of function:

```
$data_db=run_db('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status= :published ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5',array(':published' => 'published'));   
foreach ($data_db as $result) {
  $contents = $result['content'];
  $title = $result['title']; 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two essential problems with your code.

1. It connects every time it runs a query.
2. It returns data in only one format, while PDO can return results in **dozens** different formats.

Accepted answer makes it wrong, as it is just trying to reinvent PDO features, but very dirty way, with a lot of duplicated code and still failing to make it as good as with vanilla PDO.

As it said in xdazz's answer, you have to return the statement. And then use PDO's native fetch mode to get the result in desired format, using *method chaining*.

Also, you shouldn't add `try` to your code.